# How would you attack this integral optimization problem?

Tags: integration, optimization, definite-integrals

I have come across a problem in a previous exam in one of the courses I had back in university but can't figure out how to solve it.

It goes like this:

Determine real numbers $a$ and $b$ so that the integral..

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^1 \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) - (ax + b)\right]^2 dx$$

is as small as possible.

I am primarily interested on how to attack this one, and maybe not to get the solution. I tried to open the bracket and then integrate over each term separately but that turned out to be a mess rather than a help.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You certainly can handle it by expand and integrating term by term (you seem to need $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $\log(1+x^2)$ in the integration which may give you $\pi$ and $\log(2)$ in the result) and then minimise for $a$ and $b$ so still having these types of terms.  But there is scope for errors.

Answer (score 3):

Define the integral as the following function of $a$ and $b$:
\begin{equation*}
I(a,b) = \int_0^1{\left(ax+b - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)}^2 dx
\end{equation*}
We want to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that minimize $I(a,b)$. So take partial derivatives of $I(a,b)$ with respect to $a$ and $b$ and set them equal to zero:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} I(a,b) = 2\int_0^1 x \left(ax+b - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx= 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} I(a,b) = 2\int_0^1 \left(ax+b - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx = 0
\end{equation*}
Do you see where to go from there?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Consider the inner product $\langle ., . \rangle$ on the space $\mathcal{C}^0([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions over $[0,1]$, defined by
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(t)g(t) dt$$

and let $||.||$ be the associated euclidian norm.

Let $f : x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. Notice that
\begin{align*} \inf_{a,b \in \mathbb{R}} \int_0^1 \left[\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) - (ax + b)\right]^2 dx &= \inf_{P \in \mathbb{R}_1[X]} \int_0^1 \left[f(x)-P(x)\right]^2 dx \\
& = \inf_{P \in \mathbb{R}_1[X]} ||f-P||^2 \\
& = d(f, \mathbb{R}_1[X])^2
\end{align*}

where $d(f, \mathbb{R}_1[X])$ denotes the euclidian distance between $f$ and the two-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}_1[X]$.

So the $\inf$ is achieved exactly for the polynomial $Q(X)=aX+b$ which is the orthogonal projection of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_1[X]$.

To conclude, you just have to calculate $Q$. Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Outline :**

When we expand the Square , we get 3 terms :
(A) $1/(1+x^2)^2$ : we can ignore this because the Integration will be Constant , not varying with $a$ & $b$
(B) $-2(ax+b)/(1+x^2)$ : Integral is : $X=-a \log 2 - b \pi / 2$
(C) $(ax+b)^2$ : Integral is : $Y=[(a+b)^3-b^3]/3a = a^2/3+ab+b^2$

We want to minimize $X+Y$
Partial Differentiation can give the Answer here.

With that , we get :
$ - \log 2 + 2a/3 + b = 0 $
$ - \pi / 2 + a + 2b = 0 $

**Solve these Simultaneous linear Equations to get $a$ & $b$**

---

We might get :
$ a = 6 \log 2 - 3 \pi / 2 \approx -0.55 $
$ b = - 3 \log 2 + \pi \approx +1.06 $

---

We can calculate the Definite Integrals , though I used Wolfram , which gave the Integrals here :

[image: Integral]

[image: Integral]

Comment: Who-ever Downvoted will not come back to respond , but surely there is nothing **Inherently wrong** with My Answer , which is , after all , in Outline format.